# Jackrabbit Security

Tags: security, authentication, jaas, jackrabbit

I started to use Jackrabbit in my project. As i found out there is no complex LoginModule and AccessManager given. I mean we can find SimpleLoginModule but it is just a mock.
What i need is a simple LoginModule which can be configured eg from a file with users, passwords and groups. I know that i can implement my own classes, but it is hard to believe that after so many years there is no ready solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple Jackrabbit based open source / closed source projects out there that use JCR as their reference implementation and have implementations. Most probably you're best of choosing one of them in order to not reinvent the wheel. For a complete list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Jackrabbit

Answer (score 0):

Are you running inside an app server or web container? If so, you would usually expect the container to provide a JAAS implementation. For example, for instructions on how to set it up with Jetty, storing user information in a database, a properties file, or LDAP, see:

- http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jaas-support.html